# Restful services, output type by extensions

Tags: xml, json, rest, jersey, osgi

We are developing "Restful" things. We use Jersey on OSGI (Adobe's CRX, which packs Apache Felix).  The API Spec comes up with some thing dealing with conflicting restful  requests, something like if the client sends the header Accept: application/json and the request url is http://***/myresource.xml, we have to send json back (Jersey will send xml back).

Also it seems the main person (very high rank technical and knowledgeable  person) said we shouldn't use the extension such as .xml or .json for a search (non-resource), i.e., it is against the 'principle' to do something like "http://myrest/search.json?q=abc". Instead, we should do some thing like "http://***/search?output=json&q=abc" ( Implementing such a spec just makes our lives hard since manipulating what a framework (Jersey) provides is not fun).

What is your opinion?

Comment: I like to use extensions. This was you don't clutter up all of your REST methods with `@QueryParam` for format and extra logic to handle format changes in the method itself. Also, Les Hazlewood gave a nice talk about this at the SF JUG. His slides are here: http://www.slideshare.net/stormpath/rest-jsonapis?ref=http://www.stormpath.com/blog/designing-rest-json-apis . Have a look at slide 45 and 46 for his opinion.

Answer (score 1):

Why do you use a special URL at all? If the client sends the Accept: application/json he should get json. So how about using just `http://myrest/search?q=abc`

Comment: I agree. The only pragmatic reason for an extension on a resource is a hint for the browser if the user tries to save the resulting document. That argument applies to .pdf, .jpg, etc, but rarely to .xml or .json.